# Binary heap data structure - Application

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree, red-black-tree, binary-heap

As per my understanding,

Binary heap(data structure) is used to represent Priority queue ADT. It is a complete binary tree satisfying *heap property*.

*Heap property* - If A is a parent node of B then the key (the value) of node A is ordered with respect to the key of node B with the same ordering applying across the heap.

Firstly, it helps me remember term *heap*, if there is a reason behind terming this data structure as *heap*. Because, we also use the term *heap memory*.

Dictionary meaning of heap - an untidy collection of things piled up haphazardly.

Question,

After learning Reb-Black tree & AVL tree data structure,

Why do we think of new data structure(Binary heap)?

Does Binary Heap solve set of problems that Red-Black or AVL tree does not fit into?

Comment: The first known reference to a binary heap is in J.W.J. Williams’ implementation of Heapsort (Williams, J.W.J. (1964), ‘Algorithm 232: Heapsort’, Communications of the ACM 7 (6), 347-348). Blame him for the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The major difference between a binary heap and a red-black tree is the performance on certain operations.

## Binary Heap

### Pros

- It makes an ideal priority queue, since the min/max element (depending on your implementation) is always `O(1)` access time, so no need to search for it.
- It's also very fast for insertion of new values (`O(1)` on average, `O(log(n))` worst case.

### Cons

- Slow searches for random elements.

---

## RB Tree

### Pros

- Better searching and insertion performance.

### Cons

- Slower min/max searches.
- More overhead in general.

It should be noted that RB trees can make good schedulers too, such as the [Completely Fair Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler) introduced in Linux kernel v2.6.

Comment: I would expand on this a bit to say that heaps and binary search trees (RB, AVL, etc.) are trying to achieve different things. The point of a heap is to be able to find the object among a set of objects at one end of an ordering function. A heap is not meant to be used for searching for individual elements. On the other hand, a binary search tree is ideal for searching but is not good for finding the minimum/maximum element. Both data structures provide for efficient insertion and removal of elements.

Comment: Why the term, **heap**? As per the meaning, any reason for giving this term?

Comment: @overexchange With respect to the [etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymology) of the name, a binary heap is "a binary tree that satisfies the `heap` mathematical property". It is not used in the same context as [heap](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/heap) in common language.

Comment: one of the other pros of heap is that amortized complexity of  building heap of initial N elements is O(N) which is linear. But for BST its NlogN.